# Adding keys to an interface based on value?

Tags: typescript

### Scenario

My scenario here is that I have two classes, the first is a rough ObservableStore class and another base class that could have some values passed to it that are ObservableStore-s.

```
class ObservableStore<T> {
  update(value: (current: T) => T): void;
  subscribe(fn: (current: T) => void): void;
}

class OtherClass<Props extends {} = {}> {
  constructor(private props: Props) {
    for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(props)) {
      if(value instanceof ObservableStore) value.subscribe($data => this[`$${key}`] = $data);
    }
  }
}

const someInstance = new OtherClass({ someStore: new ObservableStore<string[]>([]) });
```

### Question

Is there anyway to use types to add the `$someStore` value onto the `this.props`, or is this not currently possible?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is

```
class ObservableStore<T> {
    constructor(arg: T[]) {
        // ...
    }
    update(value: (current: T) => T): void { }
    subscribe(fn: (current: T) => void): void { }
}

type Props<T> = Record<string, ObservableStore<T>>;

class OtherClass<T> {
    constructor(private props: Props<T> = {}) {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(props)) {
            // has to cast `this` for dynamic properties here, perhaps there is another workaround 
            if (value instanceof ObservableStore) value.subscribe($data => (this as unknown as Record<string, T>)[key] = $data);
        }
    }
}

const someInstance = new OtherClass<string[]>({ someStore: new ObservableStore<string[]>([]) });
```

Comment: Do you have a link for an explanation of the `unknown` type? Not entirely sure what it means.